# VSCode - error on setting change: 'Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.'

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

Per the title, I get this error when changing settings: **'Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.'**

There is a caveat to this, as there are some settings that I can still change - editor font size, color theme, default light and dark themes among some others

Namely, I am trying to edit these settings: [vscode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExNwg.png)

Here is my settings.json file :

```
{
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "explorer.compactFolders": false,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "csharp.suppressDotnetInstallWarning": true,
  "dotnet.server.useOmnisharp": true,
  "explorer.sortOrder": "type",
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/",
      "savePathReplacementPairs": null
    }
  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [],
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[scss]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.css-language-features"
  },
  "extensions.closeExtensionDetailsOnViewChange": true,
  "editor.hover.delay": 500,
  "editor.padding.bottom": 10,
  "editor.padding.top": 10,
  "editor.fontFamily": "InputSerif-MediumItalic",
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "editor.fontVariations": true,
  "html.autoClosingTags": false,
  "editor.suggest.showWords": false,
  "favouriteThemes.pinnedThemes": [
    "Darkside Light (rainglow)",
    "Monokai",
    "Solarized Light",
    "Stealth Contrast (rainglow)"
  ],
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "prettier.bracketSameLine": true,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Monokai",
  "tailwind-fold.foldStyle": "QUOTES",
  "tailwind-fold.unfoldIfLineSelected": true,
  "tailwind-fold.foldedText": ".....",
  "tailwind-fold.showTailwindImage": false,
  "tailwind-fold.foldedTextColor": "#6bc9ff",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
  "workbench.preferredLightColorTheme": "Darkside Light (rainglow)",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "csharp.suppressDotnetRestoreNotification": true,
  "window.autoDetectColorScheme": true,
  "workbench.fontAliasing": "auto",
  "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

I checked it with a JSON linter and got no errors. I also tried using the Extension Bisect command and it said it's a problem with VSCode so I know it's not an extension doing it. I get the same error upon trying to change a setting while using the 'Default' profile. I have reinstalled VSCode. I have checked for any settings that may have been from previously installed extensions and there are none.

Comment: looks fine to me. I can't see what the problem is. try doing a "setting bisect" to find out if a particular line in the JSON is causing this. comment out half of the code. if the problem goes away, uncomment that half and comment out the other half. keep doing that recursively until you either find what setting(s) is causing this, or find that isn't not something wrong with the JSON contents.

Comment: @starball thanks for the advice, but no luck... Luckily, I resolved the issue. It seems the only fix was to do a full, clean re-install of vscode. I had to delete my .vscode folder. If anyone else runs into this issue and is on mac, here's a video I followed that got it working - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSayLLlFQuA

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution you found. without more info on how to reproduce the problem, it might be more suitable to close (_not_ delete) this question this as "not reproducible".